# Simplest way to store List of Objects in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

What is absolutely the simplest way possible for storing List of simple Objects (Atributs: int, String, Date) which needs to be available through all pages in Windows Phone 8 application?

There is a lot written on this topic, but I want the simplest solution you can think of.

Example would be nice.

Comment: Simplest? `static` class with `static` field as `List<YourClass>`.

Comment: I prefer List<YourClass> in the App.xaml.cs with access via App.Current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In windows phone you can use IsolatedStorageSettings to do such kind of task. In IsolatedStorageSettings you can save any kind of data.

Here is the example to use IsolatedStorageSettings.

First create a class

```
public class MyList
{
public int IntData {get;set;}
public DateTime MyDate {get;set;}
public string MyString {get;set;}
}
//Create list 
List<MyList> myList = new List<MyList>();
myList.add(new MyList{IntData =1,MyDate = DateTime.Now.Date,MyString ="abc"});
myList.add(new MyList{IntData =2,MyDate = DateTime.Now.Date,MyString ="bcc"});
myList.add(new MyList{IntData =3,MyDate = DateTime.Now.Date,MyString ="agggbc"});

//save myList into IsolatedStorageSettings 

IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

settings.Add("MyDataKey",myList);
settings.Save();

List<MyList> getSavedListData = new List<MyList>();
if(settings.Contains("MyDataKey"))
getSavedListData =(List<MyList>)settings["MyDataKey"] ;//Here is the data
```

You can get save list in all pages of application where you want. even you close application and restart app.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyData
{
   public int MyInt {get;set;}

   public DateTime MyDate {get;set;}

   public static List<MyData> Data = new List<MyData>();
}
```

usage:

`MyData.Data.Add(new MyData { MyInt = 1, MyDate = DateTime.Today });`

etc